# Module can't update after updating core

Tags: updating

I updated my Drupal 8 website from 8.2 to 8.3. I have a module that has a block and includes a configuration form which has various data form fields. 
The block of the module appears to work fine. 
But when I try to update any of the configuration data it simply doesn't change anything! Something to do with not updating the database, maybe?

Example: I want to change the modules block name. 
The old name is "oldname" and I want it to be "newname". After typing in the new name on the configuration page and clicking save the name will still remain "oldname".

There is not a single error within Drupal or my servers log file that would explain this. 
Is there anywhere else I can look to find what the problem is?

What's changed with the new version of Drupal that might cause this?

After searching for awhile and cleaning out some old modules from the database I've finally come across an error relating to forms. It' quite long but here's the first part:
Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in Drupal\favorites\Form\AddForm->buildForm()

Comment: You flushed/cleared the cache, right?

Comment: Yes of course :) I always clear it with drush. Everything works fine apart from updating this one module :(. I was getting a "PHP Deprecated: Unknown: Use of mbstring.http_input is deprecated in Unknown on line 0" error for awhile but thats now gone since I've changed the php version. I've tried updating the module using 3 diffirent php versions just incase my hosting provider changed it on me. But still no luck :/

Comment: A little more info: when trying to change info on the config page it reloads the config page with the old values(instead of the new ones) which leads me to believe that data isn't even making it to the database :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [drush config-edit](https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/config/config-edit/), as stated in the [docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/configuration-management/managing-your-sites-configuration).

Or implement an upgrade path for you module, see [hook_update_N](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_update_N/8.2.x).

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question? Yes drush config-edit can be used to edit my modules settings but I'd prefer the browser version to work. What am I updating with hook_update_N? What's changed with the new version of Drupal?

Comment: what method do you use in the browser (https://www.drupal.org/project/config_update) ? don't know about a change. here's more about the hook_update_N: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/update-api/updating-configuration-in-drupal-8. This is meant when you want to deploy the change also to other instances ..

Comment: No I use /admin/structure/block/manage/module_name to update the module. Isn't hook_update_N for module code changes? How does this work if it's drupal core that's changed something? I have no idea why the config page won't update. I'd use drush config-edit if I could but there's just too much data in the config. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think I may be making some progress. In drush config-edit when I try and update the yml file I get two errors. 
Configuration <em class="placeholder">colorbox.settings</em> depends on the <em class="placeholder">Colorbox</em> module that will not be installed after
import.
Configuration <em class="placeholder">ng_lightbox.settings</em> depends on the <em class="placeholder">ng_lightbox</em> extension that will not be installed
after import.
Why will neither of these be installed after import?
I'm not sure I even use either of these modules..

Comment: I believe the problem  with drush config-edit is that there's some junk data in the database for modules Colorbox and ng.lightbox. I must have not properly uninstalled them and after updating drupal thinks that they're installed, when they're not. I've managed to update the module "Title" via drush config-edit but the modules website configuration page still won't work. I'm going to try and clean all traces of those two plugins out of the database and see what happens.

Comment: alright - good to have a trace thoe ;I